# How to add a select menu in jQuery Mobile's Toolbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

It is easy to add a button in toolbar, e.g.

```
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <a href="index.html" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
</div>
```

However, in the left, I want to have a select menu which allow user to choose, is it possible?